# magento 2 Ui Component Grids displays gone

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

I am working on Magento 2.2.6 .Each and every grid(Custom/Builtin) are acting strange the column names are gone and few of the grids are showing blank in action column.

here I'm attaching a screenshot 
[image]

Comment: try to indexer reindex

Comment: @RonakRathod didn't work

Comment: in database truncate ui_bookmark table and try